# Regex to find comma followed by non-whitespace characters

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I'm trying to use the JS `split()` function to split on commas that are followed by non-whitespace, while ignoring commas with any whitespace after.

For example, the string "one, two, three", should not be split at all, while "one,two, three" should be split into:

- one
- two, three

I've tried using `.split(',\\S')` `.split(',(?=\\S)")')` and other variations, but haven't had any luck with getting it to split the way I want.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: what about "one ,two" where the comma has no whitespace after, but is also not surrounded by non-whitespace?

Comment: @le_m You're correct, but I actually only care about characters following the comma. I edited the question to be clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it with regex

```
str.split(/,(?=\S)/)
```

or parse the regex string to convert

```
str.split(new RegExp(',(?=\\S)'))
```

```js
var str = 'a,b,c, d,e, f';

console.log(
  str.split(/,(?=\S)/)
);
console.log(
  str.split(new RegExp(',(?=\\S)'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this.

```
let s = 'one,two, three';
s.replace(', ', '|').split(',').map(x => x.replace('|', ', '));
```

Replace pipe with whatever works for you.