# How to match commas without space with regex?

Tags: regex

I want match the first comma, but the not the second comma in: `something,like, that`

I already try `,\S` but this match the second character of the word and I want just the comma

Comment: You must be looking for `,(?!\s)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew With a little explanation that would be an answer, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well, there is an [almost identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37886643/regex-to-find-comma-followed-by-non-whitespace-characters) also contains a solution, `,(?=\S)`, that will work here, too.

Comment: That's exactly what I need, thanks